# How to Sync Exclude from Internet Search Engines with Internal Search using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, powershell-script

I am using SharePoint 2013 On Premises. I am trying modify the values Exclude from Internet Search Engines( Present in Edit SEO Properties of a page, RobotsNoIndex field) with respect to Include/Exclude internal Search ( Present in Edit Properties, TSExternalSearch field), such that when Internal Search is marked as "Hide", "Exclude from sitemap and hide from Search Engines" is selected for Internet Search Engines. I am trying to achieve this feat for a single page in document library as of now.

Here is the partial code:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'

$siteURL = "http://dvsandboxv2-07:46000/"
$spSite = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] ($siteURL)

if($spSite -ne $null)
{
   "Site Collection : " + $spSite.Url 
   foreach($subWeb in $spSite.AllWebs)
   {
      if($subWeb -ne $null)
      {

         $spListColl = $subweb.Lists
         foreach($eachList in $spListColl)
         {
            if($eachList.Title -eq "Pages")
            {
               $PagesUrl = $subweb.Url + "/"
               foreach($eachPage in $eachList.Items)
               {

                     $eachPage.CheckOut()
                    if($eachPage['TSExternalSearch'] -eq "Hide")
                    {

                        $eachPage['RobotsNoIndex'] = 0    
                        $eachPage.Update()

                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        $eachPage['RobotsNoIndex'] = 1    
                        $eachPage.Update()
                    }
                     $eachPage.File.CheckIn("check in comment", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
                     $eachPage.File.Publish(" ")
               }
            }
         }
         $subWeb.Dispose()
      }
      else
      {
         Echo $subWeb "does not exist"
      }
   }
   $spSite.Dispose()
}
else
{
   Echo $siteURL "does not exist, check the site collection url"
}
Echo Finish
```

[image: Syncing these fields]

Can you help me with some hints or directions on how should I move ahead with this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the script below, the logic works fine, but I have faced some issue while checkin/checkout certain files. I hope, this will help other users. Also You are welcomed to suggest improvements.

```
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
} 
$siteURL = "http://dvsandboxv2-07:46000/"
$spSite = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $siteURL
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteURL


if($spSite -ne $null)
{
   "Site Collection : " + $spSite.Url 
   foreach($subWeb in $spSite.AllWebs)
   {
      if($subWeb -ne $null)
        {

         $spListColl = $subweb.Lists
         foreach($eachList in $spListColl)
         {

            if($eachList.Title -eq "Pages")
            {
               $PagesUrl = $subweb.Url + "/"
                foreach($eachPage in $eachList.Items)
                {

                    $spFile = $web.GetFile($eachPage.Url)

                    try{

                        if($spFile.CheckOutType -ne "None")
                        {
                            $spFile.UndoCheckOut()  
                            $spFile.Update()                     
                        }
                    }
                    catch{


                    #Get-PSCallStack

                    write-host -f Red "Error in UndoCheckOut" $_.Exception.Message
                    }


                   try{

                    $spFile.CheckOut()
                    $spFile.Update()
                    }

                    catch{
                        write-host -f Red "Error in CheckOut" $_.Exception.Message
                        }

                        if($spFile.GetProperty("TSExternalSearch") -eq "Hide")
                        {
                            $spFile.SetProperty("RobotsNoIndex",1)    
                            $spFile.Update()
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            $spFile.SetProperty("RobotsNoIndex",0)    
                            $spFile.Update()
                        }

                    try{
                    $spFile.CheckIn("CheckIn by Admin")
                    $spFile.Update()
                    $spFile.Publish(" ")
                    }
                    catch{
                    write-host -f Red "Error in CheckIn" $_.Exception.Message
                        }
                }
            }

         $subWeb.Dispose()
         }
        }
      else
        {
         Echo $subWeb "does not exist"
        }
    }
   $spSite.Dispose()
}
else
{
   Echo $siteURL "does not exist, check the site collection url"
}

Echo Finish
```